# sqldf query returns 0 values

Tags: mysql, sql, r, sqldf

I am having an issue running a basic query on a sample dataset(link below)
http://kbcdn.tableausoftware.com/data/Superstore.xls
using R.

I have attached my code below.

```
#read file with XLConnect
path <- file.path("/Users/petergensler/Desktop/Sample - Superstore Sales.xls")
superstore <- readWorksheetFromFile(path, sheet= "Orders")


 #Query
    test <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM superstore WHERE 'Product Sub-Category' = 'Appliances'",)
    test
```

The query executes fine, but it returns the following results:

```
[1] Row.ID               Order.ID             Order.Date           Order.Priority       Order.Quantity       Sales               
 [7] Discount             Ship.Mode            Profit               Unit.Price           Shipping.Cost        Customer.Name       
[13] Province             Region               Customer.Segment     Product.Category     Product.Sub.Category Product.Name        
[19] Product.Container    Product.Base.Margin  Ship.Date           
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Is there something wrong with my attached packages that would be causing the query to run wrong, or is it something with my data? the column I am querying on seems to be fine, as it is a type character, and specifying a literal string should match the values(unless their is trailing whitespace), correct?

I am running R on Mac OS X 10.11.5 with the following session info:

> session_info()
>   Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>    setting  value
>    version  R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
>    system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0
>    ui       RStudio (0.99.896)
>    language (EN)
>    collate  en_US.UTF-8
>    tz       America/Chicago
>    date     2016-06-08

I have also attached my packages attached to the current session as well.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxhxg_yftHNubEc4NUZTUVoxa0E

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Single quotes surround constants, not column names. Column names can be surrounded by double quotes, square brackets or backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on what G. Grothndieck said (use brackets for column names) I ran this and it worked for me:

```
#Query
test <- sqldf(x = "SELECT * FROM superstore WHERE [Product.Sub.Category] = 'Appliances'")
test
```

Most methods of reading in Data frames change spaces and hyphens in column names into `.` so you need to update that part of it.

Comment: You can use the `check.names=FALSE` argument when using `read.table` and `data.frame`.